# slf4j loging in separate file

Tags: slf4j

in a spring mvc application we are working there are lot of modules ,in each module there is different sub module,i want module wise logging ,can it ne possible by slf4j,and how can we do that,
eg:=
A is the controller class,then B delegate layer,C service layer, D dao implemetation layer,for a single module.we are using jdbc template of spring,how to get the query execution in log.

please help me detailed example.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

slj4f is the logging API, not a framework in itself.  You need to configure the logging framework you've chosen to do this.

If you use logback, have a look at SiftingAppender.  http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender